# Implementing Tomcat Custom Valve

Tags: tomcat6, tomcat-valve

I am trying to implement a custom `valve` in Tomcat, say `MyValve` which extends `BaseValve`.
I created a jar of the project and added it into the `Tomcat\lib` folder.

The next step is of configuring the `server.xml` or `context.xml`.
I tried both.
But my valve class is not getting detected.

Could someone please let me know the steps to create a valve and use it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show how you included your valve into the application context? We did exactly that and our valve works for us beautifully.

Answer (score 6):

The question is on steps required to create a custom valve and use it. So let me explain it step by step for someone else also to take advantage of it. For my example, I will use a **Java Maven Project**. ([Git Project](https://github.com/Keetmalin/Tomcat-Valve-Example))

**Step 1**: Open a new or existing maven project (you can also clone from the above repo).

**Step 2**: Add the following dependency to the `pom.xml` file.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-catalina</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.85</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

**Step 3**: Under `src/main/java` path, create a package and create a new Java Class: `TomcatValve.java` (could be any name). Extend this class by `ValueBase` class.

**Step 4**: With this, you will have to implement its `invoke` method. The entire class would look something similar to this:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import org.apache.catalina.connector.Request;
import org.apache.catalina.connector.Response;
import org.apache.catalina.valves.ValveBase;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

/**
 * @author Keet Sugathadasa
 */
public class TomcatValve extends ValveBase {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(TomcatValve.class.getName());

    public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = request.getRequest();

        Enumeration<String> headerNames = httpServletRequest.getHeaderNames();

        logger.info("Receiving request");

        while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
            String header = headerNames.nextElement();
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Header --> {0} Value --> {1}", new Object[]{header, httpServletRequest.getHeader(header)});
        }

        getNext().invoke(request, response);
    }
}
```

**Step 5**: Open a terminal, and run `mvn install`. Now in the `target/` folder, there jar should have been built.

**Step 6**: Copy this jar to `${TOMCAT_HOME}/lib` or `${CATALINA_HOME}/lib` folder. This is usually in `/usr/local/apache-tomcat9/lib`.

**Step 7**: Go to `${TOMCAT_HOME}/conf` or `${CATALINA_HOME}/conf` folder and add the following line to `server.xml`:

Classname: `TomcatValve`

PackageName: `com.keetmalin.tomcat`

```
<Valve className="com.keetmalin.tomcat.TomcatValve"/>
```

**Step 9**: Go to `${TOMCAT_HOME}/bin` or `${CATALINA_HOME}/bin` folder and run the following command in a terminal:

```
./catalina.sh run
```

**Step 10**: Next, your Tomcat server will start. Open a browser and go to `http://localhost:8080/` and go back to the terminal. You will see that the logs are being printed. Now instead of printing logs, you can do anything you wish. Hope it helps!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

What version of Tomcat are you running? The `CATALINA_HOME\lib` is the correct directory for Tomcat v6.x (and v7, I believe). If your valve is not getting picked up it could be that you are not editing the `server.xml` or `context.xml` files in your `CATALINA_BASE` directory. Are you using Eclipse IDE or something similar? If so, check your Tomcat server settings because it copies XML files from `CATALINA_HOME` (installation) to `CATALINA_BASE` (configured  instance) directory. This problem tripped me up for a while.

Comment: ok i am manually copying the jar file into the lib folder and starting the tomcat standalone. its working thanks for the advice..

Answer (score 0):

I found that I had created a jar which contained the java file, instead of the class file using netbeans.

The solution that worked for me was to create a jar with the correct directory structure for the package (`MyValve.jar\org\apache\catalina\connector\`) and stick the class file in that directory.  I put the jar in the same location (`CATALINA_HOME\lib`).

I added an entry to the `server.xml` file inside the `<Host>` section like this:

```
<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.connector.MyValve"
    classField="value">
```